# Build text statements based on number in Cell

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, counting

Not sure I am saying this right but I need to build a list of statements based on a number in a cell.  For example, in column A I have a list of room types: Office, Bathroom, Reception, Lobby, etc. and in column B I have the number of those room types in the building.

```
|  COL A |        |  COL B  |
  Office               5
  Bathroom             3
  Reception            1
  Lobby                2
```

For Office, I put 5 in column B - Bathroom I have 3 in B, and so on.

Now what I need is a way to read the number of Offices and build a statement like:
Office 001
Office 002
Office 003
Office 004
Office 005

Of course if I had put 6, then I would see Office 006.  I am not worried about getting all of the variable names into one column as each room type will then have it's own set of questions that I will figure out later.

Right now I am using messy IF statements and dragging them down the sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A:A&"♦", B:B)), "♦"))&TEXT(COUNTIFS(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A:A&"♦", B:B)), "♦")),
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(A:A&"♦", B:B)), "♦")), 
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&SUM(B:B))), "<="&
 ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&SUM(B:B)))), " 000"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Wow. Thank you!  What do the diamonds do?

Comment: they are splitting office001 from office002... otherwise you would have all offices in one cell