# Copy string based on number in adjacent column while incrementing number

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a table of 2 columns with  rows.  Column A contains text while column B contains the number of instances that should occur.  I need to generate column C based on those values, appended with an incrementing value, as shown.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | A0001 |
| B | 4 | A0002 |
| C | 1 | B0001 |
| D | 3 | B0002 |
|  |  | B0003 |
|  |  | B0004 |
|  |  | C0001 |
|  |  | D0001 |
|  |  | D0002 |
|  |  | D0003 |

I believe I was headed in the right direction using `Map(Lambda())` and `Sequence()` but struggled to get column C to expand when looking at the whole column.

| A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2 | 1 |
| B | 4 | 2 |
| C | 1 | 1 |
| D | 3 | 2 |
|  |  | 3 |
|  |  | 4 |
|  |  | 1 |
|  |  | 1 |
|  |  | 2 |
|  |  | 3 |

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60993587/build-text-statements-based-on-number-in-cell) question is an exact duplicate of mine, and the answer is 100% sufficient.  However, after venturing down this road for a while, I'd like to know if my attempt was entirely misguided or vaguely on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with REDUCE too. You won't need any splitting and empty rows won't affect the result. In my example I've tried adding 10000 in the second column and the rows were automatically added:

```
=REDUCE("Header",A2:A,LAMBDA(a,v,SI(v="",a,{a;INDEX(v&TEXT(SEQUENCE(OFFSET(v,0,1)),"0000"))})))
```

[image]